# JQuery .each() for list sorting item

Tags: jquery, sorting, each

Do the duplicate filter shuffle.js for usability. When you click on item to be added class .active at the top and bottom filter together. But .each() is not working properly. How to solve?

**original jQuery code for one filter**

```
$('.filter li a').on('click', function(event){

var $self = $(this);
var $this = $(this).parent();

if($this.hasClass('active')) {
    return;
}

$self.closest('ul').children().removeClass('active');
$self.parent().addClass('active');

$container.shuffle( 'shuffle', $this.data('group') );

event.preventDefault();
});
```

**my changes for adding class active in two filters**

```
    var $sortlist = $('.item-sort a');

function unit() {

var clikednax = (function() {
    $sortlist.each(function() {

      var $self = $(this);

      $self.closest('ul').children().removeClass('active');
      $self.parent().addClass('active');
    });

    return false;
});

    $sortlist.on('click', function(event) {
        var $this = $(this).parent();

        if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
          return;
        }
            clikednax();

        $container.shuffle('shuffle', $this.data('group'));

        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
unit();
```

See: [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/gx0ksfrd/2/)

.each() passes to the last, to have stopped on active.

Please help.

**Helped on another forum**

```
    $('.sorting-items').on('click', 'a', function(event){
    var g = $(this).parent().data('group');
    var $this = $(this).parent();

    $('[data-group='+ g +']').addClass(className).siblings().removeClass(className);

    $container.shuffle( 'shuffle', $this.data('group') );
    event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: question is not clear.. up to my understanding remove $self.closest('ul').children().removeClass('active'); line then all the li will be in active state..and let me know exact problem.

Comment: Task select an item in the upper and lower lists. Now click on the .each () moves to the last but need to remain on the click.